# WAS 6.1 to 8.5 Migration with JSF 1.1

Tags: javascript, jsf, websphere, jsf-2.2, jsf-1.2

Currently am migrating the jsf application from was6 to 8.5. I did not do any code changes or jars updation or version changes for this migration. we are using jsf-impl,jsf-api,jsf-ibm jars. after deploying into was8.5 , am getting the exception

```
0000005f ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/web/pages/epbiSearch.jsp] in application [ePBI]. Exception created : [javax.faces.FacesException: null MessageFactory).
```

Could anyone please help how to resolve this issue. Do i need to update the jars/ web.xml change. Kindly help. Thanks in advace:)...

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your WAS server with the right JSF version?
At the console, select your application, then "JSP and JSF" options, then "Select a JSF implementation that the container will use for this application. " to set the level you want, then restart WAS

The setting is for all the applications running on that server, not just the application you selected in first place.

Remember also to not include JSF implementation jars with your app. If you want to include your own JSF implementation jars, there is a section on that in the WAS knowledge center:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html